# Is it correct "What's it say?"

Tags: grammar

> > Olivia’s mother and her friends thank you for any and all contributions, and we hope to continue raising money for families like Olivia’s. Thank you, and God bless!
>
> **“What’s it say?”**
>   I jumped. I didn’t realize Emma had followed me to the table.

This text is from book *Fire in Frost*.

My question here is, is it correct to ask this way, or it should be like "**What does it say?**"

Comment: It IS like "what does it say", *What's* is just the contracted form of *what does*.  (Although it can also be a contraction for *what is*, so you have to be able to infer from context which full form was intended.)

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [Is what's a shortened form of what does?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41564/8019)

Comment: "What's it say" is referring to an antecedent (letter or note) you did not post.

Answer (score 11):

“What’s” can be a contraction of “what does,” so it is grammatically okay to say “What’s it say?”

[According to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%27s), "what's" could be one of three contractions:

1 : what is

> what's his name?

2 : what has

> what's he done?

3 : ***what does***

> what's he want?